# Problem with rich tree onselect

Tags: java, javascript, richfaces

I've a new problem with my rich:tree...
Is there how to get the Id data from selected row into javascript?
I mean, i have a bean with id, and name atributes, for example...
and then i use the tree showing the names (but i injet the bean)...
When i click in the element, i want to call a javascript function named 'teste'...
and there i want to get the id, from the selected row...

```
function teste(){
   var selectedId = ?
}
```

Is there how to get the id into js function?